# Camunda external task nodejs save link to variable

Tags: node.js, camunda

I upload a file into OpenKM and get the URI to the file as response. I want to save the link as processVariable.

```
const { Client, logger } = require("camunda-external-task-client-js");
const { Variables } = require("camunda-external-task-client-js");
const { exec } = require('child_process');

const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
  
const config = { baseUrl: "http://localhost:8080/engine-rest" };
const client = new Client(config);

var moment = require("moment");

client.subscribe("Rechnung", async function({ task, taskService }) {

  console.log("*** Processing task " + task.id);
  var uploadedFile = task.variables.get("rechnung");

  const file = fs.createWriteStream(uploadedFile.filename);
  const request = http.get("http://localhost:8080/engine-rest" + uploadedFile.remotePath, function(response) {

        response.pipe(file);
        file.on("finish", () => {
                file.close();
        });
  });


  var cmd = "curl -u okmAdmin:admin -H \"Accept: application/json\" -X POST -F docPath=\"/okm:root/manuel/" + task.id + "_" + uploadedFile.filename + "\" -F content=\"@" + uploadedFile.filename + "\" http://172.20.16.90:8080/OpenKM/services/rest/document/createSimple";

  var newlink = "";
  
  exec(cmd, (err, stdout, stderr) => {

        newlink = "http://172.20.16.90:8080/OpenKM/frontend/index.jsp?uuid=" + JSON.parse(stdout).uuid;

        if(err)
            console.log("error " + JSON.stringify(stderr));

  });

  var processVariables = new Variables();

  processVariables.set("link", newlink );

  await taskService.complete(task, processVariables);

});
```

The variable is created but the link is empty. I tried encodeURIComponent but without any success. Can you tell me what should i do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the async function does not wait for exec to finish. I solved it this way

```
const { Client, logger } = require("camunda-external-task-client-js");
const { Variables } = require("camunda-external-task-client-js");
const { exec } = require('child_process');

const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
  
const config = { baseUrl: "http://localhost:8080/engine-rest" };
const client = new Client(config);

// rechnungseingang
client.subscribe("Rechnung", async function({ task, taskService }) {

  console.log("*** Processing task " + task.id + " - " + task.processInstanceId);

  console.log(JSON.stringify(task));

  // get the uploaded file
  var uploadedFile = task.variables.get("rechnung");

  // save it to disk
  const file = fs.createWriteStream(uploadedFile.filename);
  const request = http.get("http://localhost:8080/engine-rest" + uploadedFile.remotePath, function(response) { response.pipe(file); file.on("finish", () => { file.close(); }); });

  var createFolder = "curl -u okmAdmin:admin -H \"Accept: application/json\" -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" -X POST -d \"/okm:root/ibass/" + task.processInstanceId + "\" http://192.168.0.31:8080/OpenKM/services/rest/folder/createSimple";
  await sh(createFolder);

  // upload to openkm
  var cmd = "curl -u okmAdmin:admin -H \"Accept: application/json\" -X POST -F docPath=\"/okm:root/ibass/" + task.processInstanceId + "/" + uploadedFile.filename + "\" -F content=\"@" + uploadedFile.filename + "\" http://192.168.0.31:8080/OpenKM/services/rest/document/createSimple";

  let newlink = await sh(cmd);

  var processVariables = new Variables();

  processVariables.set("link", "http://192.168.0.31:8080/OpenKM/frontend/Download?uuid=" + newlink);

  await taskService.complete(task, processVariables);

});

function sh(cmd) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {

        exec(cmd, (err, stdout, stderr) => {

            let link;
            link = JSON.parse(stdout).uuid;
            if(err)
                console.log("error " + JSON.stringify(stderr));
            resolve(link);

        });
    })
}
```